# Grok filtering in logstash for multiple defined patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to filter my logs matching few patterns I have. e.g:

```
E/vincinity/dholland_view_sql_global/IN/Cluster_Node/SSL-CACHE/Dsal1
F/vincinity/dholland_view_sql_local/IN/Cluster_Node3/SSL-CACHE/Dsal4
```

R/vincinity/dholland_view_sql_bran/IN/Cluster_Node/Sample/vr1.log

Now I want to grep these 3 paths from a bunch of logs: basically the pattern that I want to extract is logs containing "vincinity" "sql" and "IN" so with regex it would be simply `*vincinity*sql*IN*` 
I tried this grok filter:

```
grok {

    match => { "Vinc" => "%{URIPATHPARAM:*vincinity*sql*IN*}" }

  }
```

Then I get _grokparsefailure in kibana - I'm brand new to grok, so perhaps I'm not approaching this correctly.

Comment: Your expression is close. `(?<field_name>.*?vincinity.*?sql.*?IN.*)` would probably work well for you. The `.*?` construct is the non-greedy equivalent of `.*` and should make this perform somewhat better as a result. Less sub-string searching.

Answer (score 0):

From the [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

> The syntax for a grok pattern is %{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC}

The way the grok filter should work is

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => "%{PATTERN:named_capture}"
  }
}
```

Where `message` is the field that you want to parse, this is the default field that most inputs place your unparsed loglines in.

The `URIPATHPARAM` pattern is one [predefined in logstash](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns#L47) through a regex language called Onigurama. It may match your whole log message, but it will not capture certain chunks of it for you.

For help constructing a grok pattern, check out the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html), they link to a couple useful pattern construction tools.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for using a [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) in your grok block is:

```
(?<field_name>the pattern here)
```

or you can define your own custom pattern (using regular expression) in seperate file (my-pattern.txt) like this :

```
MYPATH_MUST_BE_UPPERCASE Regex_Pattern
```

save it in `./patterns` directory and then use it this way:

```
grok {
     patterns_dir => "./patterns"
     match => ["message" , "%{MYPATH_MUST_BE_UPPERCAS:path}"]
}
```

in your case :

```
(?<vincinity>(?>/\s*.*?vincinity.*?\s*)+)
(?<sql>(?>/\s*.*?sql.*?/\s*)+)
(?<in>(?>\s*.*?(IN).*?\s*)+)
```

Comment: this is usefull but then I get _grokparseexception

Comment: Check your regular expression at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com there should not be any new lines( \n or enter) among your expressions

Comment: Now this is weird the regex is filtering right on http://regexr.com/ but not in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ .*vincinity.*_sql_.*IN.*